# Why does VALIGN not work in a ReportLab Table?

Tags: python, reportlab

I have been attempting to generate a table with reportlab, and I have been having trouble with the VALIGN command in TableStyle. It seems to have no effect. Whenever I create a table, the text is overlapping the grid lines, and the VALIGN command has no effect on the position of the text. Below is a toy example that reproduces this effect. The image below shows the overlapping text.

```py
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, Frame, Table, Spacer, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, A4
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from datetime import datetime
from random import random


from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

c = Canvas('L:/table_test.pdf', pagesize=letter, bottomup=False)
width, height = letter

CENTER_X = width/2

#c.translate(inch, inch) # Set origin
c.setFont("Times-Roman", 12) # Perfecting font

# Draw a shape
c.setStrokeColorRGB(0, 0, 0)
c.setFillColorRGB(0, 0, 0)

rand_data = [[round(random(), 2) for x in range(10)] for k in range(10)]
t = Table(rand_data)
t.setStyle(TableStyle([("BOX", (0,0), (-1, -1), 0, colors.black),
                       ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0, colors.black),
                       ('VALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'BOTTOM'),
                       ('ALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'CENTER'),
                       ('FONT',(0,-1), (-1,-1), 'Times-Bold'),]))

t.wrapOn(c, 0, 0)
t.drawOn(c, 1*inch, 1.5*inch)

c.showPage()
c.save()
```

What my table looks like
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `bottomup` option is broken, with any values other than `1` (default), text rendered incorrectly.

You need to specify `rowHeights` for `Table` to `VALIGN` have effect, otherwise cell height is adjusted to font height + padding.

```py
t = Table(rand_data, rowHeights = inch)
```